# Math underpinnings of software testing?

Tags: testing, math

In my software engineering course, we recently (briefly) covered testing.

Over the course of the discussion some topics came up that made me wonder about the math underlying software testing (such as finer vs. coarser test sets, using equivalence classes to partition infinite input spaces into "testable" sets, etc).

Are there any resources available exploring the math behind software testing?